# How to stack focus so that both the background and the subject are sharp?

Tags: portrait, focus-stacking

I would like to take a portrait with a 50mm lens, where both the subject and the background are sharp. The usual way to do this would be to either switch to a wide-angle lens or to dial-down the aperture, but I'm wondering if this is possible with focus stacking? The approximate workflow would look like this:

1. Take a picture of the person from a tripod
2. Have the person quickly step out of the frame
3. Take a picture of the background
4. Merge the photos in post-processing - **how to do this?**

I'm looking for a way to do step 4 automatically, rather than through painstaking post-processing work in Photoshop. I presume this should be possible with modern software.

Comment: How "Automatic" are you seeking? "Select both images and click one button" automatic, or "layer the photos and use a few tools with a few minutes of cleanup" kind of 'automatic'?

Comment: Possible answer [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18740/what-software-is-available-for-macro-focus-stacking). Although some cameras can also do it automatically, too...

Comment: @TheLuckless at most 2-3 minutes per picture would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe had a good blog which shows how to do this in Photoshop [here](https://create.adobe.com/2019/1/29/focus_stacking_in_ph.html).

Basically:

- take multiple photos with different areas in focus
- import photos as layers to one image
- auto align layers
- auto blend layers
- adjust masks, tone, color, etc to your liking.